# JavaScript getter return promise value

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

How would I make a **JavaScript** object getter return the return value of a promise?

See the snippet below to get an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

```js
var my_object = {
    get latest() {
        return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
    }
};

console.log(my_object.latest); // Promise
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to call an asynchronous function (axios.get) and return the value synchronously? just think about it for a moment to see how impossible that is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `my_object.latest.then(x => console.log(x))`:

```js
var my_object = {
 get latest() {
   return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(function (response) {
     return response.data;
    });
 }
}

my_object.latest.then(x => console.log(x));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.16.2/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could simply this to: `my_object.latest.then(console.log)`

Comment: From "return the return value of a promise", I think the OP wants `my_object.latest` to equal the return value of the Promise, not an actual Promise (although it's not totally clear). In that case, the only way to do this is using async/await.

Comment: `the only way to do this is using async/await` - as long as the call to `my_object.latest` is in a function that is tagged `async`